# Replacement mic for an AKG D202E1 for studio spoken word recording

Tags: microphone, studio, selection

Not been the best of nights at our Talking Newspaper studio tonight - one of our five AKG D202E1 mics has died! (the metal barrel part of the barrel was a bit loose, and it seems to have been twisted one time too many - the five wires inside have pulled apart!)
This leaves me with a conundrum - from what I have read this evening, the D202 is a bit "special" in it's set up and sound. Our recordings are entirely spoken word, with opening/closing music from CD/MP3/Minidisk.

Is there a mic I could buy that would fit with the sound of the other four mics?

Working D202's seem to be going for £120+ on ebay, and even the broken one would fetch a bit - would it be better to get a new set of mics, and sell the D202s to cover some of the costs?  As a rule, what sort of mic is best suited to recording spoken word in a studio setting?

(A final option would be repair - is there somewhere in the UK that could repair one of these mics, and not cost more than replacement?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend the Studio Project B1 as a low Budget solution and the Neumann TLM 103 (= U87 with only cardoid pattern) as a high cost alternative.

Both Mics do have a nice Volume in the lower frequencies and a boost at around 2000-3000 Hz which automatically leads to a "easy to understand recording". Also both Mics have a very natural frequency response in the highs. A slight EQ boost at 8000-12000 Hz and a Deesser will result in a very nice and "warm" top-end.

Of course the TLM 103 has an overall better sound than the B1 but it is around 6-10 times as expensive.

If you do only spoken word, also test the Shure SM 58. It has not that strong bass frequencies, but it delivers ready to use recordings, that are not phat but very very easy to understand.

So if you want a phat narrator/tv-ad like sound -> B1 and TLM 103
If you just want a voice over for a tutorial or to give some information -> Shure SM58

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. The Studio Project B1 looks a good choice and sounds good on a YouTube review i saw, so I've placed an order for one!